# Loop through array to assign value for every nth item

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array containing a range of numbers 1-100:

```
$range = range(1, 100);
```

I want to loop through and assign each a value of 1-24. So 1=1, 2=2, 24=24, but then also 25=1, 26=2, 27=3, etc...

How can I loop through `$range` and apply said values to each number?

Note: I would preferably like to use a `for`loop, but will take any valid answer.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: what do you mean by --> _and apply said values to each number?_

Comment: @jitendrapurohit You know how when you loop through an array you apply values to each item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulo operator (`%`) is the answer

```
$range = range(1, 100);
$rangeValues = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($range); $i++){
    // using modulo 25 returns values from 0-24, but you want 1-25 so I use ($i % 24) +1 instead which gives 1-24
    $rangeValues[$range[$i]] = ($i % 24) +1; 
}
```

Comment: First answer, and it works.  Thanks very much for your help @cashbee!

Comment: haha i was just testing my answer because of your first comment there and thought to myself: wasn't this exactly what you wanted? anyway, seems to be so. Glad to help :)  (I guess you took my unedited answer first)

Answer (score 1):

Try : php modulo operator (%).

```
//example loop
$range = range(1, 100);
$yourIndex = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($range); $i++){
   //$yourIndex will reset to 1 after each 25 counts in $range
   $yourIndex[$range[$i]] = ($i + 1) % 25;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$range = range(1, 100);
$offset = 1;
$limit = 24;

for($i = 0; $i < count($range); $i++)
{
    $range[$i] = $offset+($i%$limit);
}
var_dump($range);
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting your required solution, you can also use the below code -

```
$range = range(1, 100);
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
  if($i < 24){
   echo $range[$i].' = '.($i+1);echo "<br>";
  }else if($i < 48){
   echo $range[$i].' = '.($i-23);echo "<br>"; 
  }else if($i < 72){
    echo $range[$i].' = '.($i-47);echo "<br>";  
  }else if($i < 96){
    echo $range[$i].' = '.($i-71);echo "<br>";
  }else{
    echo $range[$i].' = '.($i-95);echo "<br>";   
  }
}
```